What happens if we plug a 1500W device on a limited-power 300W inverter from 12V DC to 220V AC in my car?
for example if I plug a mobile air conditionner for house (eg. a 1500W mobile air conditionner) directly in my car 12V power supply using an inverter 12V DC to 220V AC between ?
Can it finish with expositions or fire ?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

A 300w inverter is only good to 300w (minus whatever overhead it has). If you go over that, one of two things can happen (depending on how the inverter is setup). It will either blow a fuse, or if it is set up so, the device will shut down due to being overloaded. Either way, you won't get your 1500w device to work. Most devices are setup this way. There is one alternative, that being if it doesn't have a fuse nor have a "safety shut off", it could go into thermal nuclear meltdown (the inverter). Yes, that's a little tongue-in-cheek, but hopefully you get what I'm suggesting. Any which way, you also stand the chance of damaging your AC unit as well.
Bottom line is ... don't do it.
